# Unable to scan command barcodes with a Socket Mobile 8Ci

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, socketscan

I'm using a Socket Mobile 8Ci scanner with an Android device and have configured the scanner to enable UPC-A UPC-E, EAN8, EAN13 and interleaved 2 of 5 and disabled all other symbologies.

After configuring the scanner, I unpaired it from the mobile device by pressing and holding the trigger and power button.

Now when I try to pair the scanner it does not scan the barcode that is displayed during the pairing process. It does not even scan the command barcodes or factory reset barcode. They used to work earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The 1D and 2D command barcodes are Code128 and DataMatrix, respectively.

Since you disabled Code128, the scanner will not decode the command barcodes (including the factory reset command barcode).

If the scanner were still paired, you could re-enable Code128 in Scanner Settings, but since it's not, the easiest solution is to factory reset your scanner.

#### Factory resetting a CHS

1. Power on the CHS
2. Press and hold the trigger button
3. Press and release the power button
4. Wait ~15 seconds until you hear a beep
5. Release the trigger button

You will hear a series of beeps and the scanner will turn itself off. When you power it on, it will be in a factory fresh state.